# Setting up MacBook Pro with Linksys 802.11.n router

Tags: macbook

I have a MacBook Pro (running Mac OS X 10.5). And I just brough a Linksys 802.11 n router (WRT 160N).  I have followed the installed disk to configure the router. And it said the configuration is completed successfully.  But I can't connect to LinkSys router wireless from my MacBook Pro.  I have made sure I entered the right security key (I copy and paste that from the setting file generated by Linksys install program).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are locked out, you could always RE-SET the linksys to factory default (push button usually for 10sec or so), once it restarts, connect DIRECTLY to is using a standard network cable, and configure it using the web interface, I would advise against using any installation disk, those are usually more trouble than they are worth.

Set your own password (a secure one, use this place for help generating something good: http://www.geekwisdom.com/dyn/passwdmeter)

That should get you back to square one, so you can configure it correctly.  From there on, just turn on the wireless (if it already doesn't come configured). Set the encryption type you wish to use, and once EVERYTHING IS configured as you like it, THEN disconnect from the cable, and try wireless.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up the router? What type of password? Some more information on how you set it up would help greatly. What options or checkboxes did you select and setup during the router setup?

Did you happen to enable MAC address authentication in addition to setting a password?

Comment: I just follow the installation wizard.
I think I use "Better security" option during the setup. (WEP/WEP2). 
I just use the generated security key as my password.

That is. Th rest is done automatically by the install program. I did not change anything and It did say the configuration is successful.

So I am not sure what you mean by 'MAC address authentication' I don't change that myself.